# Two hyphens get changed to a long dash in titles (-- vs -)

Tags: bug, status-completed, title

As seen in the title of [What is the difference between -​- and - before a command option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27321567/what-is-the-difference-between-and-before-a-command-option) two hyphens are converted to a single long dash:

[image: hyphens]

This is a problem when one considers that there is a difference between --foo and —foo (which isn't -foo).  For commands and options, this conversion can make reading the title of the question difficult and lead to confused answers (and search engines?).

Comment: To bypass this: put an invisible space between the two hyphens.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi does that mess up *other* searching?

Comment: I found another example: [Overload of operator -- (prefix)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28907161/overload-of-operator-prefix)

Comment: see [this answer](https://superuser.com/q/156640/438160) for how to type a zero-width space in Windows. For me, the solution using the Chrome console worked.

Answer (score -12, accepted):

This has been the case for years; since Stack Overflow was first released, IIRC:

> Note that the fancy entities code (for **post titles only**, of course) is based on a simplified subset of [SmartyPants](http://daringfireball.net/projects/smartypants/).
>
> - Straight quotes (' and ") into “curly” `&lsquo;` and `&ldquo;` entities
> - Dashes (-- and ---) into `&emdash;` entity
> - Three consecutive dots (...) into `&hellip;` entity

-- [Smart quotes in parentheses point the wrong way ("example") ["tst"] {"tst"}](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34587/smart-quotes-in-parentheses-point-the-wrong-way-example-tst-tst/35141#35141)

Comment: The last two can be bypassed by putting invisible characters between the displayed characters. I think it's by design (because sometimes the characters are in fact needed); is it a bug?

Comment: No. The intention is to allow normal folks to write attractive titles without deviating from normal ASCII conventions - and for that purpose, it works.

Comment: Given that the double dash is syntactically significant in some situations, I think the utility of converting it to `emdash` is outweighed by the misleading titles it causes. It should be removed from the list of substitutions.

Comment: Maybe we could compromise and have two dashes go to an endash?  That's what TeX does, IIRC.

Comment: I appreciate good typography, and appreciate this conversion in most software and on most sites, but on programming websites where `--` is real syntax that comes up in questions, this is an inappropriate and slightly harmful choice. I'd bounty, but there are no bounties here, and repeats keep being duped to this inactive thread...

Answer (score 10):

We have now disabled all [Smarty](https://daringfireball.net/projects/smartypants/)-like modifications text in titles.

From now on, the title text saved for the post is the title text that will be displayed.

If folks want em-dashes (`ALT-0151`) and fancy quotes (`ALT-0145` through `-0148`) to appear in titles, they are welcome to add them. But we won’t convert it automatically any longer.

> we’re no longer the
> smarty-pants who makes changes
> to typography