# Question title wrongly auto-converts triple double quotes into two curly quotes and a straight

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, title

[Triple single quote vs triple double quote in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28511229/triple-single-quote-vs-triple-double-quote-in-ruby) shows up wrong on the question page, and I initially tried editing the quotes to fix them, before seeing that my changes hadn't changed the displayed title!

That's semantically wrong, since curly quotes in Ruby are not the same as straight*, so SO is silently **damaging** the question, and there is **no workaround possible**. [bobince appears to have the right idea here of annihilating smart quotes in titles entirely](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/34636) (found through [Two hyphens get changed to a long dash in titles (-- vs -)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278604/two-hyphens-get-changed-to-a-long-dash-in-titles-vs), which *has* a workaround and is thus not a dupe.)

<sub>*AFAIK</sub>

Comment: Do those really need to be in the title though? I mean, without the pre-formatted text supplied by code formatting, they just look like a bunch of ticks and you can't even tell they are single versus double quotes. So why not just explain it via text and exclude the quotation marks in the title?

Comment: @animuson: In my proportional font (Helvetica Neue 16-point), the difference is slight, but noticeable in the questions list. More to the point, the specific case of single vs double quotes is rarer by a large margin than simply needing double quotes in the title in the first place. And having your first impression of a question be that it's a ridiculously trivial typo, when that's not the case, is quite unfortunate.

Comment: @animuson do we really want to expect all new users to **know** that we don't support quotes in the title? isn't it better to design a system that behaves as expected? just because they don't **need** to be there doesn't mean people won't put them there. in that case we shouldn't damage the question.

Comment: Uber-Meta post: [Fix Markdown/SmartyPants in question titles](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/68844)