# Inconsistent presentation of -- (two minus signs) in title after edit attempt

Tags: bug, status-completed, title

Based on [Two hyphens get changed to a long dash in titles (-- vs -)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278604/two-hyphens-get-changed-to-a-long-dash-in-titles-vs) it looks like `--` should be printed as `—` `&emdash;`.

Example: [Precedence of ++ and -- operators in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373976/precedence-of-and-operators-in-java)

[image]

But after attempting to edit (which I canceled later), title used two minus signs instead of emdash.

[image]

To get emdash back we need to reload this question.

Comment: Tested on Google Chrome 52.0.2743.116 m, but this looks more like server-side problem than client-side.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't get it. Replacing two consecutive dashes with a longer single dash is positively a deadly sin, in the context of programming languages. It sounds like you are complaining this bug got fixed?

Comment: @RadLexus I am able to see -- and dash in same place of question's title, so there is inconsistency. If it is correct for dash to replace -- is not subject of this question, but I agree with you and this opinion: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278604/two-hyphens-get-changed-to-a-long-dash-in-titles-vs?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment162722_278606.

Comment: @RadLexus Agreed, but in any context. Typographically speaking the double dash can only have come from impoverished cases of type in the 19th century. Why they persisted beyond that, e.g. in silent movie title cards, is a mystery. We all have em dashes now, let us use them where we want and leave the double dashes strictly alone. No second-guessing please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've  added support for *most*  (not quite all) of the title tweaks into the inline editor. This should make the preview from inline editing **mostly** consistent with what the server would render for the same title.

Comment: would this be considered [tag:status-completed] then?

Comment: @Magisch Probably not since that *mostly* part doesn't include example from my question. But there is no pressure with fixing it now, since this bug doesn't really cause serious problems. I posted this question just to inform that it exist.

Comment: @Pshemo the "mostly" includes everything mentioned in this question; I just haven't deployed it yet