# HTML <!-- comments --> look bad in question titles

Tags: bug, title

Related to [Two hyphens get changed to a long dash in titles (-- vs -)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278604/7586)

HTML comments in titles look broken, with the opening "<!—" being converted to an em-dash, while the closing "-->" remains valid.

Putting aside the discussion on whether smart quotes in a programming site is a bad idea or a terrible idea, this just looks ugly and inconsistent.

Stack Overflow question for example: [Confused about <!-- ko if: $parent.name == name --> in knockout js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14589493/7586)

Comment: To the Stack Overflow Team: If we *type* the title one way, we *want* it that way. *Please* don't change our titles. :)

Comment: Also, you can fix this problem by inserting a [zero width non-joiner](https://unicode.flopp.net/c/200C) in between the two characters.

Answer (score 20):

The client-side code causing the error is a regex looking for 2-3 dashes and a space:

```
e=e.replace(/---?(\s)/g,"—$1")
```

It can be corrected to also require a space before the dashes:

```
e=e.replace(/(\s)---?(\s)/g,"$1—$2")
```

This will also resolve cases like `i--`.

From a quick check in the data explorer, it looks like in most people do place spaces on both sides for emdashes: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/730462